# OnError img replace issue

Tags: php, html, image, src, onerror

Hi guys from reading the answers on this particular page i stumbled upon the onerror flag and thought that would help me out...

but when i merged it with my script it deffo doesnt work for me, im not sure if my php script is getting mixed up here, if someone could advise a novice on what is wrong with my code please.

```
<td><a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/tbphotos/<?php echo $row['PHOTO3']; ?>"><img style="height: 150px;width: 150px;" src="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/tbphotos/<?php echo  $row['PHOTO3']; ?>; onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/thunderball.jpg'"></a></td>
```

The actual image is in /images/tbphotos
the replacement image is /images/thunderball.jpg

TIA
Lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed up a few errors. try the following:

```html
<td>
  <a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/tbphotos/<?php echo $row['PHOTO3']; ?>"><img style="height: 150px;width: 150px;" src="<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/tbphotos/<?php echo  $row['PHOTO3']; ?>" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='<?php echo ROOT_URL; ?>images/thunderball.jpg'"></a>
</td>
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY PERFECT. (i did up vote but says im under 15 reputation) Thank you

Comment: @LeeDF Awesome :)

Comment: i cant answer as correct for 7 mins but i will click it when the timer is up :)

Comment: @LeeDF Do not fear you will get there with the rep. I'm building mine so I can finally down vote lol

Comment: Just to save the later reader sometime, the change in the code is the closing `"` of the img's `src` attribute , the OP was closing the attribute with `;`